# Kitchen faucet low pressure

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, water-pressure

[image]

I believe the low pressure from my kitchen faucet hot and cold is from this blue connector. The faucet and parts are new. If I disconnect this, the pressure seems normal, but with it connected it seems to have a very spread spray which is what’s probably causing the low pressure. That’s not normal right? I will probably try to replace this connector even through it should be new.

Comment: What do you mean by "very spread spray"?

Comment: Sprays in a wide direction

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Inside the connector there is a flow restrictive: I popped it out and needed a needle to pick some particles out. My hot water tank probably needs a good flushing. But the flow is fine now.

Comment: Aw crap. That's what I was going to suggest. But, really great job and thank you for getting the information on here.